# Can we connect 2 cat6 cables as a input to a cat 6 jack

Tags: networking

I am trying to wire my house with lan cable.
I wanted to know whether we can connect 2 lan cables as input to cat6 jack. As a result I want those 2 cables which we connected as input to be joined. Also, I will get the output slot to plug in for use.

Please let me know if there are any other better ways.

Comment: You're posing an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What is the real, underlying issue?  What is this *"jack"* connected to?  What are these two *"cables"* connected to?  What is an *"output slot"*?

Comment: One cable is coming from the internet modem and then I need connect to a wireless router and to another room for pc. So at the place of wireless router I have socket with only one cat 6 jack. So I will be connecting the cable from the internet modem to this jack as input. And then I need to run the cable to the other room as well. So I was wondering whether I can join these 2 wires by connecting both as the input for the jack.

Comment: @NaveenWilson In short: you can't. in order to connect three or more devices (modem, router, pc), there must be a switch between them to which all three (or more) connect directly. However, I'd be surprised if your internet modem and/or wireless router don't actually have several LAN ports built in and already act as a switch. -- Historically, good old 10-megabit connections used only 2 of the 4 pairs of cat6 and one could thus use one cable as two cables, but you'd need to split into two at both ends. Just don't. And many modern devices don't even know how to "speak" at only 10 mbps

Comment: Thanks @HagenVonEitzen. Internet Modem do have 4 ports but the pipe through which the wire are running can fit only one. I will connect to router and then will take the out to again to the room.

Comment: doubt *"Internet Modem"* have 4 ports, you are probably talking about *residential gateway*. Please explain *"socket"* - do you mean cat6 outlet in wall? Yes you can join two wires by just connecting to available LAN ports on your device instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking to wire one CAT6 ethernet cable into TWO keystone jacks](https://superuser.com/questions/1079667/looking-to-wire-one-cat6-ethernet-cable-into-two-keystone-jacks)

Answer (score 1):

> So at the place of wireless router I have socket with only one cat 6 jack. So I will be connecting the cable from the internet modem to this jack as input. And then I need to run the cable to the other room as well. So I was wondering whether I can join these 2 wires by connecting both as the input for the jack.

No, Gigabit Ethernet does not allow 3-way connections. It needs direct point-to-point connections, i.e. one jack—one cable. If you need to connect multiple devices to a single Ethernet port, use an "Ethernet switch" which will give you more ports.

(Especially if you spent extra for Cat6 cable... The sometimes suggested *passive hub* trick would limit you to 100 Mbps at most, probably even less than that in reality. Don't create potential future problems.)